# I want to save some analytics views to a permanent table periodically (hourly) in MySql

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers

I created some views to analyze many tables so that the view has delay.
But I need to run the faster query from the analytics views.
So I am going to save the views to a table periodically.
What is the good solution for this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this can be achieved with an EVENT. Make sure the global system variable EVENT_SCHEDULER is enabled.

```
set global event_scheduler=on;
delimiter //
drop event if exists hourly_job //
create event hourly_job on schedule every 1 hour starts now() do 
BEGIN
insert into your_analytic_table select * from your_view ;  -- put whatever you want to do in the body part
END//
```

The event_scheduler will execute the code in the body part based on the set interval, which in this case is set to every 1 hour. The time interval can of course be changed to meet your requirement. e.g every 10 minute

Answer (score 1):

That's one of several ways to build and maintain [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

For periodic summarization as blabla_bingo suggests, you could have an index on a `DATETIME` to fetch just the rows in a given hour (for summarization) or "remember where you left off".  I like the latter because that could lead to a "continuous" summarization, if that is suitable.

Be cautious on picking the rows you need. to summarize; there can be subtle hiccups (missing rows) in the case of rows `COMMITted` out of order; etc.

IODKU is useful for most techniques, including the updating of summary tables at the same time you insert into the 'Fact' table.

For example, when updating a daily summary based on "dimensions" dim_a and dim_b:

```
INSERT INTO summary
        (dy, dim_a, dim_b, ct, sum_x, ...)
    SELECT
        DATE(datetime) AS dy, dim_a, dim_b,
        COUNT(*) as ct, SUM(x) AS sum_x
      FROM fact_table
      WHERE id > $left_off
        AND id < $stopper
      GROUP BY
        DATE(datetime), dim_a, dim_b
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        ct = VALUES(ct) + 1,
        sum_x = VALUES(sum_x) + x,
        ...
```

where  `$left_off` might be `MAX(datetime)` from the previous update, and `$stopper` is some limit on that source table.  (Please provide more details on your example; maybe I can be more specific.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I read your post carefully many times.
I would appreciate if you can share more detailed references for IODKU.
Thank you so much again.

Comment: @ziqiangjin - I added an example.